# Smith Normal Form and Inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, svd, smith-normal-form

Given an matrix $ K \in GF(2)$, of dimension $m\times n$ ($m>n$) we can write its Smith normal form as
$$
    A = P K Q
$$
where $A = \mathrm{diag}(a_1,a_2,\dots,0,0)$ (here $a_1=a_2=\dots=1$, since we are in $GF(2)$). Playing around with some examples it appears that $(Q A^T P) K = I_n$.

I followed the idea behind SVD and the pseudoinverse, and it seems to work, but I cannot formally convince myself that's the case. Am I fooling myself with some (too) simple examples?

*Is this Correct?*

We are looking for a matrix $X$ such that $XK=I_n$, so $X$ has dimensions $n\times m$.

If we choose $X = QA'P$ then we have $K = P^{-1} A Q^{-1}$ from the previous equation, and thus we have
$$
   XL = QA'PP^{-1}AQ^{-1} = QA'AQ^{-1} = Q Q^{-1} = I_n
$$
Since $A'A = I_n$. Do we know that $P$ and $Q$ are in $GF(2)$?

Comment: How would a matrix end up in $GF(2)$ (presumably the field with two elements)?

Comment: yes $GF(2)$ is the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$  or as you said the field with 2 elements, and it turns out, see here https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Smith+normal+form that if a matrix is in a ring $R$ than $P$ and $Q$ are defined in the same ring.